# Can't connect to my Node.js server

Tags: iptables, node.js

I have a VPS (on linode) where I installed Node.JS on.

My server.js file is as follow:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337);
console.log('Server running on port 1337');
```

When I try this on my server:

```
wget http://localhost:1337
```

It does work and downloads the response. But externally, Google Chrome is saying Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to xxx.xxx.xx.xx:1337

This is the output of the Iptables:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport dports ssh
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             loopback/8          reject-with icmp-port-   unreachable
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:www
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG level debug prefix `iptables denied: '
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:4711
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:1337
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:1337

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:1337

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

What could be wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try another port. 3000 should work.